# Can't connect to MongoDB Compass with provided connection string

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I have created a cluster and would like to access it with MongoDB Compass.

Via `Connect` -> `I have MongoDB Compass` I get the following connection string:

```
mongodb+srv://myname:<password>@myname.nauqp.mongodb.net/dws
```

When I enter this string in MongoDB Compass and insert my password and replace `test` with the name of my DB, the connect button is disabled and the following error message below it:

```
querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.myname.nauqp.mongodb.net
```

I also have the same problem when I want to establish the connection via mongoose. There I get the error message:

```
Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.myname.nauqp.mongodb.net
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting ...
```

My config looks like this:

```
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const connection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
        })

    } catch (error) {
          // error handling
    }
}
```

The MONGO_URI in my .env file looks like this:

```
mongodb+srv://myname:<password>@myname.nauqp.mongodb.net/dws?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**MongoDB Compass Version:** 1.22.1 (1.22.1)

**Node Version:** v14.15.0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's the cluster's name after the @

```
mongodb+srv://myname:<password>@clustersname.nauqp.mongodb.net/dws?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: In my case, the cluster is called exactly like the username. Is this a problem?

I've just replaced it with "myname" here. But even if I change the name, the button in MongoDB compass is still disabled..